# Groovy script to decodebase64 and message digest SHA1. unable to run the script

Tags: groovy

I'm pretty new to **Groovy scripts**. I'm using script to perform `decodebase64` on string and do `Messagedigest` **SHA1** on the data. I had managed to get below code but its not working.

```
import java.security.*;
def Message processData(Message message) {
    //Body 
    def body = message.getBody(String.class);
    String decoded = body.bytes.decodeBase64().toVarchar();
    MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
    byte[] digest  = sha1.digest(decode.getBytes());    
    digest = new BigInteger(1, digest).toString(16);
    message.setBody(digest);
    return message;
}
```

Input would be:

> kIAUQJVfhfLaTF2G4WouvCmZqA2zhFhujfqe3g1I4WBJobFrBWcXKG5XoPM1MQZF9UeoM0o99tf8FHVEkEIkN1s0Pw7vXyHurkbiY/Dic56Fqa+PovU9gU4US+oLHoEMSpoDMtrVtAskS0h6bCgv1Hph/1QHTlVeto/GIw0Obb9CtSqlfhoXL8ZqCBMlsWClF8q31PZaD4vt8ZRzjm/fnA1YsH8Fo5PfxdWFEVrsprvDyUHuRvr0CHbDyE7qszgYA+Ri0ylnulPEqOlsBvNpiXoiEtoOnFOjZrWmLCM6IjnR8b2efnTRQsELdYr3FjRbg1kLDz3xUDGBwTplF31CSw==

After decoding the input has `unicode characters` in it. I'm unable to get to it. After `SHA1` the output would be of 40 char.

Can you guys please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what `toVarchar()` is doing, but I suspect it's at fault...

```
import java.security.MessageDigest

def msg = 'kIAUQJVfhfLaTF2G4WouvCmZqA2zhFhujfqe3g1I4WBJobFrBWcXKG5XoPM1MQZF9UeoM0o99tf8FHVEkEIkN1s0Pw7vXyHurkbiY/Dic56Fqa+PovU9gU4US+oLHoEMSpoDMtrVtAskS0h6bCgv1Hph/1QHTlVeto/GIw0Obb9CtSqlfhoXL8ZqCBMlsWClF8q31PZaD4vt8ZRzjm/fnA1YsH8Fo5PfxdWFEVrsprvDyUHuRvr0CHbDyE7qszgYA+Ri0ylnulPEqOlsBvNpiXoiEtoOnFOjZrWmLCM6IjnR8b2efnTRQsELdYr3FjRbg1kLDz3xUDGBwTplF31CSw=='

def digest = MessageDigest.getInstance('SHA1').digest(msg.decodeBase64())
def result = new BigInteger(1, digest).toString(16)

println result
```

Gives me

```
17a88df21eb9ad8669864f3ccdd435bfc1e054aa
```

Comment: Super... it worked for me. Can you please let me know how to format the output eg: 17a88df21eb9ad8669864f3ccdd435bfc1e054aa need to format it to 17a88df2-1eb9ad86-69864f3c-cdd435bf-c1e054aa

Comment: You could just do `result.toList().collate(8)*.join().join('-')` to group them into groups of 8 chars separated by a `-`.  Good news, please accept the answer if it helped (there should be a tick you can click somewhere near the top of this answer)...  Have fun!